Unity 6 - Animation clips causing player to not be able to move
I made some extra animation clips and their mere existence causes the player not to be able to move. I don't know why, when I delete the new animation clips I can move the player again. I tried undoing code to see if it was the code, but it wasn't.

sounds like maybe animation root motion is messing things up, try turning root motion off

@Ruzihm it is already off

As soon as an animation that exists in the AnimatorController holds any keyframe on a property - even if that clip/state is not being currently played - this property is basically locked / owned by the Animator so you can't overwrite it from script.
One way would be to set things in LateUpdate or using WaitForEndOfFrame as this is executed after the animation update loop. Both is pretty dirty as it basically "fights" against the Animator and overwrites the values after Animator has already set them => You can't rely on e.g. incremental movement as in the meantime the Animator might already have reset the property.
The alternative is to use a base AnimatorController that does NOT have your new AnimationClips which animate the position but only the according states.
And then only while those clips are needed and the object is rather supposed to be moved by the animation then use an AnimatorOverwriteController which only then has the according animations.

Otherwise as mentioned you can also nest the player under another root object, move the root by script and only animate the player relative to that root object.

It is probably because your animation changing position values that one game object you want to move.
If you want to move an object in animations, create a parrent Game Object and animate that.
Same as well for rotations and scales.

The thing is I'm not even playing the animation, it just exists in the Animation Controller and still immobilizes my player

Are you sure this is the reason? If you remove the animator controller, will the player move?

@Bekranker I think instead of create a parrent Game Object and animate that. you rather wanted to say create a parrent Game Object and MOVE that, while keeping the animations as they are => or in other words have the animations local/relative to the new parent root object which is being moved

Yess, sorry for misunderstanding. Thanks for reply,

@Daniel if you have an animation clip and that animation clip set to default animation, it'll play it still (if the loop toogle uncheck it will be run just for once). And that will lock the Transform Component. İf you want to show that error you can write me from linkedin than we can go with discord or etc.

what is this one animation for? if it's updating local position and another script is meant to move that same transform, it won't move. you've said it's not playing the animation, which tbh I wouldn't know for sure but if you've got an animation moving your characters highest (in the hierarchy) transform, it's probably just bad in general and probably causing the problem.
